# Using a constant current LED regulator with a regulated DC power supply as a constant current power supply for making colloidal silver

Tags: power-supply

Basically I noticed the expensive constant current colloidal silver generators brag a lot about using constant current.  As you decrease the voltage the size of the particle decreases and a constant voltage makes small particles initially then larger as the current increases based on the decreasing impedance.  I am thinking of using an LED regulator that is constant current 500mA and a 36V DC regulated power supply to achieve the same results. The question is will the LED regulator work for that scenario.  The initial resistance will be quite high as distilled water is not a good conductor and as silver is transferred from anode to the cathode that resistance will decrease as positively charged ions are suspended in the solution.  Just not sure if the regulator will vary the voltage enough with the range of resistance it will based upon.

Comment: The first question is:  How much current do you need?  Is 500mA too high, too low, don't know?

Comment: If you are planning on using this stuff as a medicine, just **don't.**  It's nothing more than quackery, and will (over time) make you look like a smurf.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Colloidal silver is complete bunk as medicine, and causes a condition called argyrosis, that is, your skin turns blue-gray. Stay far, far away from this junk. Unfortunately there’s a lot more of this sort of thing lately as folks panic about Coronavirus, while some choose to capitalize on the fear and ignorance. Don’t be that person.

Comment: https://nccih.nih.gov/health/colloidalsilver "Colloidal silver can cause serious side effects. The most common is argyria, a bluish-gray discoloration of the skin, which is **usually permanent**. ... Scientific evidence doesn’t support the use of colloidal silver dietary supplements for any disease or condition."

Comment: I'm still interested in the electrolysis, though wonder if this is better on [chemistry.se]

Comment: @jonathanjo:  Whether constant current is better (or not, and how much current) is some way might be better suited to the chemistry site, actually building a constant current source belongs here.

Comment: That’s a rather narrow view, don’t you think? While asking about making a current source is technically within the bounds of an SE EE question, the *intent* is at best questionable, and at worst, illegal. It’s not a very big leap to make here - we’re talking about *colloidal silver* after all, one of the biggest-ever hokums foisted onto gullible people that nevertheless has the ability to cause harm. Stay far, far away.

Comment: It's a clear electrical engineering question so I say we answer it. This forum is about engineering, not health or politics.

Comment: It is antiethical, if not unlawful, to knowingly support an activity that could promote a fraud or lead to bodily harm. Making colloidal silver falls squarely into that category, assuming OP’s likely intention to use or sell it as a quack cure. This overrides any legitimate ‘engineering’ question.

Comment: @hacktastical "lead to bodily harm"...many, many answers on this site are related to situations that could cause bodily harm. High voltages. Lithium batteries. And we have absolutely no evidence of fraud. Your biases are showing.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson - in those cases - high voltage, batteries etc. - I answer those questions with care, citing references to place them in proper context, as any ethical answerer should. Now, if someone asked, "how to make an IED fuze ignitor", would you answer such a question? I would hope not, even though it's a 'clear engineering question'. The only difference between this question and the IED one is a matter of degree. Given the OP's mention about "expensive constant current colloidal silver generators" means that they've been researching this realm of quack medicine. Why? OP isn't saying.

Comment: @hacktastical Suit yourself. Nobody is forcing you to help anyone where you have a moral objection.

Comment: @Drew it’s not about me. If you can’t see the moral hazard you’ve fallen into, that’s very definitely on *you*. Engineering isn’t an island unto itself, beholden somehow only to pure logic. It is a social act with real-world consequences. In this case, OP could poison himself or others manufacturing this outdated ‘cure’ that fell out of favor in the 1930s because *it doesn’t work* and *it is harmful*. See the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Skipping over whether using colloidal silver as medicine is a good idea or not...

The answer to your electrical questions is: *It depends on the exact supply.* We need a datasheet.

If the supply is designed only for driving LEDs it may make some assumptions about the load that will not hold with your use case.

I would recommend buying a general purpose power supply with constant voltage and constant current modes. They're common and quite cheap. Some examples:

Panel mount DC-DC step-down (needs a higher voltage than the output voltage) "UCTRONICS U5168":
https://smile.amazon.com/UCTRONICS-Numerical-Stabilized-Converter-Adjustable/dp/B01LWXAC5E/

Standard bench power supply "Eventek KPS305D": https://smile.amazon.com/Eventek-KPS305D-Adjustable-Switching-Regulated/dp/B071RNT1CD/

Another DC-DC converter, with pot inputs instead of an LCD: https://smile.amazon.com/WHDTS-1-2V-35V-Converter-Adjustable-Constant/dp/B0819Y8PJZ/

DC-DC **boost** converter. (requires lower voltage than the output voltage) https://smile.amazon.com/NOYITO-Converter-Transformer-Adjustable-Regulator/dp/B07F56VKZT/